# How does jQuery find Dom elements

Tags: jquery, parsing

I've been looking at the source code in jQuery https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src, but I haven't been able to find where and how jQuery parses and finds elements that are passed in.

For example

```
$("div.red")
```

I'm assuming that somewhere in the jQuery source (I thought it was in jQuery.fn.init), it takes `div.red`, and then somehow splits the class from the div, passes the class to `getElementsByClassName`, and then runs through that array to see that each of the elements with that class match the element passed in, in this case a div.

Is this how jQuery works? Can somebody point me to the source code where this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery uses the sizzle selector engine. Look at the source code there to make sense of that. http://sizzlejs.com